# pure pagination tools django

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-views

i want to create a paganator for my main page and i want to use only on my posts using pure_pagination tools.

i foolow this steps [django-pure-pagination](https://github.com/jamespacileo/django-pure-pagination)
my first view

```
def index(request):
return render_to_response("blog/movies_list.html", {
    'ranking' : Movies.objects.all().order_by('-rating')[:3],
    'likes': Movies.objects.all().order_by('-like')[:3],
    'categories': Category.objects.all(),
    'posts': Movies.objects.filter(publisheddate__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-publisheddate')
     })
```

my view after

```
def index(request):
    try:
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1),
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = 1,
    objects = ['john', 'edward', 'josh', 'frank']
    p = Paginator(objects,request=request)
    people = p.page(page)
    return render_to_response("blog/movies_list.html", {
        'ranking' : Movies.objects.all().order_by('-rating')[:3],
        'likes': Movies.objects.all().order_by('-like')[:3],
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'people':people,
        'posts': Movies.objects.filter(publisheddate__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-publisheddate')
        })
```

first i dont know how is the line

```
objects = ['john', 'edward', 'josh', 'frank']
```

but not work show me error at line `p = Paginator(objects,request=request)`

error

```
TypeError at /
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'per_page'
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should *show it in your question* so that we know what it is.

Comment: i update my question

Comment: `objects = ['john', 'edward', 'josh', 'frank']` ...you should replace this with your `posts` queryset

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use the [`django.core.paginator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/)

You need to import the correct one for your third party package

```
from pure_pagination import Paginator
```

Django's core paginator takes in two arguments, the object, and the number to show per page

```
p = Paginator(objects, 5)
```

Constructor signature for [`core.paginator.Paginator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator):

```
class Paginator(object_list, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True)
```

Comment: i import that 'from pure_pagination import Paginator '  how to use django.core.paginator on my first view ?

Comment: @user27818 - I've updated my answer (I haven't tested this and not sure if `request` is a valid kwarg, just taken from your own code) I just looked in docs though and it would appear as though it isn't

Comment: if u runserver with your update show me error' int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple''

Comment: @user27818 - That possibly relates to a different issue, you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35017060/1324033) your question with the stack trace.

Comment: i find solution using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/      thnx you